# Workbench doesn't show API version beyond 35.0

Tags: api, workbench, reports-api, spring16

As per the known issue:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008dNiAAI

This feature would be available only for version 36 (and not below 36, once the known issue is fixed). However I am not able to see version above 35 when accessing workbench. https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

How can I upgrade to version 36?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does take some time and someone has to include the API version into the code as well as the newest version of the API.  You can monitor the project [here](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/forceworkbench) or create your own [pull request](https://github.com/ryanbrainard/forceworkbench/commit/0793b25957c173a2a02de9de6513a13eae317401) similar to the one for api 35.0 and submit it.