# Public Imageurl

Tags: apex, force.com, attachment, files

We're looking for a way to upload a picture, either as Attachment, File or Content Delivery. We want to use that Image on an external website. We just need to get a public URL of the photo itself (no salesforce webpage that displays the picture as of Content Delivery).

Is there a easy way to make an image public with Apex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can insert a ContentDelivery, and then get the URL of that. If you have a set of ContentDistributions (and can fill in some blanks that I've removed becomes I'm relying on some of our internal company libraries) then you can do this:

```
Map<Id, ContentVersion> contentDocumentIdToNewestVersion; // Populate this yourself

List<ContentDistribution> distributionsToInsert = new List<ContentDistribution>();

for(Id thisContentDocumentId : contentDocumentIds) {
    ContentDistribution newDistribution = new ContentDistribution(ContentVersionId  = contentDocumentIdToNewestVersion.get(thisContentDocumentId).Id, 
                                                                Name='External Link',
                                                                PreferencesNotifyOnVisit = false);
    distributionsToInsert.add(newDistribution);
}

if(!distributionsToInsert.isEmpty()) {
    insert distributionsToInsert;

    distributionsToInsert = [SELECT Id, ContentDownloadUrl, ContentDocumentId
                            FROM ContentDistribution 
                            WHERE Id IN :(new Map<Id, ContentDistribution>(distributionsToInsert)).keySet()];
}
```

Then, you can use the `ContentDownloadUrl` field to get the URLs.

Note that each org is allowed 20k downloads via content distribution URLs per 24 hours. If your external site is going to require more than that, you'll need to think again. I ended up putting these URLs behind an AWS CloudFront cache, which is nice and easy.

Comment: Just checked it through Workbench, but there isn't a "ContentDownloadUrl" field within the ContentDistribution object.

Comment: It's new in v40 (Summer 17), so maybe you're on an old API? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm

Comment: Ok, let me check it. Is there also a way to create public url for files via APEX (It's possible through UI). That would be much easier for the user to upload files instead of content deliveries

Comment: This code is inserting the ContentDeliveries so the user doesn't have to. You could, for example, run this code in a trigger on ContentDocumentLink so that any File attached to a particular Custom Object type would automatically have a ContentDistribution generated.

Comment: Just wanted to doublecheck, could it be there is actually no workbench for 40.0 API?

Comment: Looks like someone has to manually add the newest version numbers to Workbench and haven't done it yet for v40: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110708/workbench-doesnt-show-api-version-beyond-35-0/110710